# Why can I access collections.abc in tests, but not in production?

Tags: python, module, pytest

I've been writing a module, and the tests have all been passing, but I found out that when I import the module in the REPL or in an executable, I get an `AttributeError`.

`ilinkedlist.py`:

```
import collections


class _List(collections.abc.Hashable):

  def __hash__(self):
    return 0
```

`test_ilinkedlist.py`:

```
import ilinkedlist


def test_hash():
  assert hash(ilinkedlist._List()) == 0
```

The test passes, but here is the REPL session:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jan  1 1970, 00:00:01) 
[GCC 5.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ilinkedlist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/luther/learning/python/module-question/ilinkedlist.py", line 4, in <module>
    class _List(collections.abc.Hashable):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'abc'
```

I also have an executable that throws the same error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ilinkedlist

print(hash(ilinkedlist._List()))
```

Why would `abc` sometimes be missing from `collections`? How is it possible for this to work in tests but not elsewhere? I don't believe modules ever share their "global" namespaces, so I don't think that's what's causing it.

My module must use both `collections.abc` and the toplevel `abc`, so I'd rather not rename one of them with `import`--`as` unless necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the collections package, it has following hierarchy:

```
$ tree collections/                                   
  collections/           
  ├── __init__.py        
  └── abc.py
```

so when you do `import collections`, python imports `__init__.py` which doesn't contains `abc.py`.

To fix your problem you should import like following:

```
from collections.abc import Hashable

class _List(Hashable):

    def __hash__(self):
        return 0
```

This will make sure that we are always importing `Hashable` from `collections.abc`.

Comment: I've got it working now, but if that's the way it works, do you happen to know how it apparently works differently under pytest?

Comment: Yeah that part is surprising to me, maybe someone else can help.

Comment: Can confirm this weirdness for python 3.7.5.:
Different behaviour in ipython vs. python.

Comment: i have following settings and i'm getting same behavior i.e. pytest test is passing but on python terminal i'm getting `AttributeErrror`

platform darwin -- Python 3.8.0, pytest-5.2.2